# [NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My created application crashed when executing the below lines of code 
where c1 is an integer variable.

```
NSString *path = c1.stringValue;
```

Shows the following error in log:

> -[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x5566e80 2011-05-11 14:56:15.813
>   e-TREND[1552:207] Uncaught Exception
>   happens!! (NSInvalidArgumentException:
>   -[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x5566e80) 2011-05-11 14:56:15.816
>   e-TREND[1552:207] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSCFString stringValue]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x5566e80'

if anyone have any idea to solve this issue , please answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

> where c1 is an integer variable

What does that mean?  How is c1 declared?

If `c1` were an `int`, then `c1.stringValue` wouldn't even compile.

The dot syntax only works when the object reference -- `c1` -- is of a specific object reference type (not `id`) and that reference-- that class-- responds to the method.

So, you have something like:

```
MyThingThatRespondsToStringValue *c1;
```

And then you are, somewhere, assigning an instance of `NSString` to that variable which leads to the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",c1];
```

Comment: if `c1` were a string, why do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assume C1 is the instance of `NSString`.

Try with

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithString:c1];
```

OR

```
NSString *path = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:c1];
```

Comment: If `c1` were declared as an `NSString`, the OP's code wouldn't compile.